# What is the meaning of the term "number of milliseconds the CPU has spent in user/nice/sys etc mode" when we use os.cpus() method in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, operating-system, cpu, cpu-usage

I was trying to get the computer resources (CPU and memory usage) being used using the core node module - `os`. Can someone please explain what does time the CPU spends in a particular mode (user/sys/nice/idle etc) means when we use the method `os.cpus()`? See this for reference: *https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_cpus*
Is it the time spend per cycle of the CPU core or something else? For what duration is this time calculated?
Thank you!